# Python max-by function?

Tags: python

Example:

```
print max(chain_length(i) for i in xrange(1,10001))
```

This returns the maximum/biggest "chain_length" (an arbitrary function), but what I want is the `i` value for input that produces the biggest value.

Is there a convenient way to do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
max(xrange(1, 10001), key=chain_length)
```

Comment: Didn't know about the `key` parameter. That's awesome! Thank you.