# Pythonic maxby function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, max

A `maxby(list, f)` takes a list of objects and a function `f` as arguments, such that `f` applied to any object in the list returns a number. Then `maxby` returns the object `x` in the `list` for which `f(x)` is maximum.

What's the pythonic way to write something like `maxby(list, f)`? Is it already implemented, or I have to write one?

Comment: Which types of objects is in list? Not all objeCt types can be comparable.

Comment: @felipsmartins that's why there is an `f`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python max-by function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337023/python-max-by-function)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's builtin in Python, just use [`max()` function with *key* parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
max(list, key=f)
```